# Defining open sets in topology

Tags: general-topology

How do we define open sets in topology? Is the only requirement that the set is included in the topology? Let $ X $ be a set and $ \tau $ be a topology on $ X $. $ U $ is a subset of $ X $ and $ U $ is an element of $ \tau $. Is that enough for saying that $ U $ is an open set?

Comment: A topology is a set $X$ and a collection $\tau$ of subsets of $X$ that satisfies some basic properties (has the entire space and empty set as members, closed under unions, and closed under finite intersections). A member of $\tau$ is *called* an open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a topology on a set is defined as the set of open subsets of that set.

Comment: Thank you very much.